# Как вызвать два метода подряд через точку?

Tags: java, ооп, методы

есть класс myDate. Как сделать так, чтобы я мог вызывать методы следующим образом: myDate.reverse().getDate();
myDate.getDate();

```
class myDate {
static private Date today = new Date();
static private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(“dd.MM.yyyy”);
public private String date = format.format(today);

public static String getDate() {
 return date;
}

public static String reverse() {
 String[] split = date.split(“\\.”);
 date = split[2] + “.” + split[1] + “.” + split[0];
 return date;
}

public static void setDate(String string) {
 date = string;
}
}
```

Comment: `public private` - ??? определитесь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется [Fluent Interface](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Реализуется при помощи возврата экземпляра того же класса из методов:

```
public class Example {

   public Example method1() {
      System.out.println("method1");
      return this;
   }

   public Example method2() {
      System.out.println("method2");
      return this;
   }

   public Example method3() {
      System.out.println("method3");
      return this;
   }
}
```

После это используется так:

```
new Example().method1().method2().method3();
```

Answer (score 1):

Для вызова метода чем точку, предыдущий метод должен возвращать объект того же класса.

```
public class Michael {
    public startTheGame() {
        return new Michael();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.print("That is true!");
    }
}
```

Затем создаете объект и вызываете методы:

```
Michael theBestBoy = new Michael();
theBestBoy.startTtheGame().print();
```

Answer (score 1):

С полным примером, хотя не совсем понял, что у вас с модификаторами доступа. Объект класса в любом случае придется создавать,ибо в таком синтактисе нужна ссылка на не статический класс

```js
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.*;
class qew{
public static void main(String[] args){
myDate d = new myDate();
System.out.println(d.getDate());
System.out.println(myDate.getDate());
System.out.println(d.reverse().getDate());
System.out.println(myDate.getDate());
}
}

class myDate {
static private Date today = new Date();
static private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
static private String date = format.format(today);

public static String getDate() {
 return date;
}

public myDate reverse() {
 String[] split = date.split("\\.");
 date = split[2] + "." + split[1] + "." + split[0];
 return this;
}

public static void setDate(String string) {
 date = string;
}
}
```

Отдельно класс

```js
   
class myDate {
static private Date today = new Date();
static private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
static private String date = format.format(today);

public static String getDate() {
 return date;
}

public myDate reverse() {
 String[] split = date.split("\\.");
 date = split[2] + "." + split[1] + "." + split[0];
 return this;
}

public static void setDate(String string) {
 date = string;
}
}
```

Если необходимо, могу привести немного другой пример работы с объектом и таким синтаксисом

Comment: А можно ли все это сделать не создавая экземпляр класса? Допустим как это уже можно сделать с классом String.    String.valueOf().equels(); и String.valueOf();

Comment: String.valueOf() это просто статический метод класса String в который заносишь объект какого либо или просто примитивного типа и он возвращает объект String.  String.valueOf().equals()  -  так как  String.valueOf() возвращает объект String , а у этого класса есть метод s1.equals(s2) , а объект естественно может вызывать методы своего класса, он вызывает equals() и сравнивает значения двух объектов

Comment: Очень хорошое объяснение. Я прям прозрел)

Comment: @Ignat Удачи в разработке )